# Sbt always do fully recompile after restart sbt

Tags: scala, sbt

```
[success] Total time: 132 s, completed Aug 25, 2017 3:08:56 PM
> compile
[success] Total time: 0 s, completed Aug 25, 2017 3:09:07 PM
>                                                                                                                                                                                                               
$ sbt
[info] Loading global plugins from /home/jilen/.sbt/0.13/plugins
[info] Loading project definition from /home/jilen/Workspace/wx-web/project
[info] Updating {file:/home/jilen/Workspace/wx-web/project/}wx-web-build...
[info] Resolving org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.4 ...
[info] Done updating.
[info] Set current project to wx-web (in build file:/home/jilen/Workspace/wx-web/)
> compile
[info] Compiling 574 Scala sources and 3 Java sources to /home/jilen/Workspace/wx-web/target/scala-2.11/classes...
```

As the log says when I start sbt, it do fully recompile which is already compiled before.

- sbt.version 0.13.15
- scala.version 2.11.11

Answer (score 0):

Finally, it turns out to be a [bug](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/3666) of sbt incremental compiler.